# Vim73 not picking up any color, including scheme

Tags: vim, putty, color-scheme

I had been using Vim through Putty on a windows machine for the last 6 months and everything was fine.  After seeing somebody using a new text editor that had amazing colors, I decided to venture down the colorscheme path.  This worked great for about 24 hours and then i decided i wanted to add a bunch of plugins which required me to recompile my VIM.  After doing so (using vim73), I NO longer can get any colors in my vim.  It is black and white with a foggy background.  My .vimrc file has not changed neither has the color scheme i was using, zenburn.

I get no errors, except that the colors just aren't working.

I did a

```
strace -o vim_strace vim
```

to make sure that my .vimrc file was being loaded but still nothing.  I'm wondering if i have some legacy file that is actually get read after the fact and overwriting my desired colors.

Any thoughts on this one??? Pretty much stranded with no way out.

UPDATED INFO:
@epsilonhalbe: I used this build of VIM and configuration options:

```
hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim
./configure --enable-rubyinterp
make
```

This killed my colors.  I couldn't find a 'colors' option in the configuration file.

@kev:I tried running a colors:zenburn which did nothing, however, trying another scheme like color:desert does in fact change the colors, BUT, everything is still black and white, just various shades.  Its like i am using black and white instead of colors, but it appears that it is reading and applying the scemes, just incorrectly.

My .vimrc file is located -> ~/.vimrc

Comment: which plugins did you add and with what flags did you compile it? (could be an interesting info;))

Comment: What about run `:color zenburn` manually in vim?

Comment: What does `vim --version` say?

Comment: Maybe this may be of help: http://superuser.com/questions/411091/compiled-latest-version-of-vim-colorschemes-not-working-any-more

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for all the help but I figured it out.  It looks like when i compiled again the default functionlaity of syntax was turned off.

All I had to do was add:

```
:syntax on
```

to my .vimrc file and I am back in action.

Thanks again!!